# How to detect a page redirect?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect

I have a page that should be displayed slightly differently if users are coming from a particular link.

I.e.
The normal page is `example.com/foo`

If someone clicks on a link to `example.com/foo-bar` I want it redirected to `example.com/foo`, which can be done with the following line in a .htaccess file:

```
Redirect permanent /foo-bar /foo
```

I was planning to then using the following javascript to determine which page a user has come from:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.write(document.referrer);
</script>
```

Which does print out the referrer URL if the user has come from a normal link on the site to `/foo`. But if they have clicked on a link to `/foo-bar` it prints out the URL of the page with the link, rather than the `/foo-bar` address that I need.

Is there a way to redirect a URL to another URL, and detect this on the page redirected to?

(Note that that the difference of content on the page isn't critical, so if the 1% of users with javascript turned off see the wrong thing when they go to `/foo-bar` it wouldn't be an issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your redirection code to:

```
Redirect permanent /foo-bar /foo#redirected
```

and then in /foo:

```
if( window.location.hash == 'redirected' ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is the way to proceed.

Comment: Have had to undo accepting your answer I'm afraid. Have noticed that in IE8 it chops off everything after the `#`.

Comment: @Jonathan Then do it via query string parameter: e.g. `/foo?ref=redirected`)